# How can I conect a NodeJS app to a MongoDB running in a Docker container on AWS?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy my first MEAN stack application ('weatherapp') to production on AWS.

I deployed my NodeJS/Express/Angular app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (preconfigured Linux machine running Node). This works fine and I can view the app in the browser.

Separately I created a docker container running MongoDB and deployed it to AWS / EC2 following the steps in this post:
https://blog.codeship.com/running-mean-web-application-docker-containers-aws/

My question is - how do I connect the two?

In my NodeJS app I was connecting to my local Mongo instance locally like this:

'mongodb://localhost:27017/weatherapp'

What steps can I take to find out what the connection string should be for my production Mongo instance on docker?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify where the parts are running? Are you trying to connect your applications (that is running in Elastic Beanstalk) to a single EC2 instance running a single MongoDB container?

Comment: That's correct - the NodeJS application is running in Elastic Beanstalk and a single instance of MongoDB is running in a Docker container in a single EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is two-fold. We need to set some options on the Docker side in the EC2 instance and then some security groups and configuration on the AWS side. First, we'll start on on the Docker container side.

## Container

When you run the MongoDB container, you will want to do two things:

- Persist the data to disk.
- Open the MongoDB port to the container.

To persist the data to disk you will want to do something like `-v /data/db:/data/db`. This will make the MongoDB data available at `/data/db` on the host. This makes sure that an accidental deletion or upgrade of the container doesn't lose any data.

Next, we need to publish the MongoDB port so that applications external of Docker can connect to it. The default MongoDB port is `27017` so let's publish that using `-p 27017:27017`.

If your original command for starting MongoDB was:

```
docker run --name mymongodb -d mongo
```

Then the new one would be:

```
docker run --name mymongodb -d -p 27017:27017 -v /data/db:/data/db
```

## AWS

Now, we need to edit the security group of your EC2 instance and configuration of Elastic Beanstalk.

### Security Groups

First, take a look at your Security Groups in the EC2 console. You will have a group for the Elastic Beanstalk application named similar to `awseb-e-xanf9hqrw3-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1N2T1AI2H05I8` with a ID similar to `sg-07fb8c43`. We'll use this ID in the next step so copy it somewhere.

Now find the Security Group attached to your EC2 instance running the Docker container. You will need to add a new rule to this group allowing access to the MongoDB container. Edit the group and add a new inbound rule for:

- Type: Custom TCP
- Protocol TCP
- Port range: 27017
- Source: sg-07fb8c43

This will allow the Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances (using `sg-07fb8c43`) to access the MongoDB port on your Docker EC2 instance.

### Elastic IP

You'll likely want a more static IP address for your EC2 instance in case it reboots. Navigate to the Elastic IPs section of the EC2 console and allocate a new address to your Docker EC2 instance.

The new Elastic IP will be the address you use in your Elastic Beanstalk configuration to connect to MongoDB. If your address was `54.67.29.50` then your application would connect to `mongodb://54.67.29.50:27017`.

### Elastic Beanstalk

Now, instead of hardcoded this address in your Node.js application, you should configure your application to pull the information from an environment variable. In your application, you should read the MongoDB URL from something like `process.env.MONGO_URI`. Then, in your Elastic Beanstalk application configuration, navigate to the Software Configuration and then down to Environment Properties. Here, you create a property name of `MONGO_URI` and the value as `mongodb://54.67.29.50:27017`. This will allow you to easily change the MongoDB instance should it ever change or if you launch multiple environments with different databases.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I've gone through your instructions in close detail and made all of the changes but unfortunately I'm still unable to connect to the database from my app (504 Gateway timeout).

Comment: I've tried the following:
1) Going through the instructions again and verifying everything
2) Deleting the EC2 instance with Mongo and recreating it from scratch
3) Tried adding the connection string in the node app both as an env variable and hardcoded.
4) Tried adding an additional inbound rule on the docker container, opening it up to all ports, from any location (for temporary testing).



The exact string I am using from my production node app to reference the DB is: mongodb://52.11.88.113:27017/weatherappdb

Not sure what to try next - appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: First, verify that you can access it from the EC2 Docker instance. Can you `telnet 52.11.88.113 27017` from inside the EC2 instance?

Comment: When I user 'docker-machine create' to create the aws instance I see that a keypair is generated but I don't see an option for downloading it from the EC2 console. At the same time, I see that several '.pem' files are added under '.docker/machine/machines/aws03/' but I am not sure which one to use.

Comment: Also, I noticed that when I use the command: 'docker run --name mymongodb -d -p 27017:27017 -v /data/db:/data/db' the docker container exits immediately. That is, when I run 'docker ps -a' I can see that the instance has exited. I understand that this is because of the '-d' flag which runs the container as a background process. I am a little confused though because in production, I would need the container running Mongo to always be running. What is the recommended approach for starting the docker container in prod - would I want to start it up as a foreground process? Thanks again.

Comment: Update: I finally got connectivity from the app to the db!

For some reason with this command, the container was running and then immediately exiting:

docker run --name weatherapp mongo -p 27017:27017 -v /data/db:/data/db

However, when I ran it like this - the process stayed up and I was then able to connect from the app:

docker run --name weatherapp mongo -p 27017:27017

So there was some problem with this part: ' -v /data/db:/data/db'

I still want to back up the data in the host though, so I will investigate further. Maybe I need to create those folders in the host first (?).

Comment: You should use `docker logs` to output the log from the failed MongoDB start and see what it is complaining about. Likely just a permissions issue (it may run as a `mongo` user in container).